# How to Develop Barcode Application, What is the best practice

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I want to develop a bar code application to print barcode labels. I'm using vb.net as front and sql server as d/b can any suggest me what is the best practise like I should use crystal report to create report and print labels or I have to have SdKs of TSC bar code printers to develop this application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will be the outcome of the application (stickers, A4)? What tools do you have available?

Comment: I have label of size: 4x4, visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008.